# Starting activity on dialog after button clicked

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, dialog

I'm a noob in Android Studio and now i'm stuck creating my app.I created a Floating action button in my main activity and clicking on it i'd like to display a dialog asking to user what to do.In this specific case i have 2 options to choose and on clicking each of them i'd like to open 2 different activities,called AddProductNoEan and AddProductEan .I tried with the code below,but got an error after closing the last brace at the end of my onCreate.I already used the same procedure in other apps and it worked,so after trying many times in different ways without succeed i'm totally stuck!Does anybody have some hint to solve this issue or a better way to accomplish my aim?Thanks in advance!

```
public class Inventory extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    FloatingActionButton add;
    AlertDialog.Builder build;


    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);
        add = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(icon)
                .setPosition(4)
                .build();
        add.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Inventory.this);
                build.setTitle(R.string.delete);
                build.setMessage(R.string.question_delete);
                build.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent noean = new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProductNoEan.class);
                        startActivity(noean);
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
                build.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent eans = new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProductEan.class);
                        startActivity(eans);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();
                return false;
            }
        }};


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                Intent adne = new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProductNoEan.class);
                startActivity(adne);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                Intent lista1 = new Intent(Inventory.this, ListaProdottiNoEan.class);
                startActivity(lista1);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                Intent ade = new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProductEan.class);
                startActivity(ade);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_activity_lista_prodotti_ean);
                Intent lista2 = new Intent(Inventory.this, ListaProdottiEan.class);
                startActivity(lista2);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_activity_all__products);
                Intent ap = new Intent(Inventory.this, All_Products.class);
                startActivity(ap);
                break;
            case 6:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_activity_gallery);
                Intent ga = new Intent(Inventory.this, Gallery.class);
                startActivity(ga);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inventory, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((Inventory) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add two tags to Your question: one about language and second about platform. It will help other to find Your question.

Comment: Thanks for ur hint Michas,i just edited adding related tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just error in ending `onCreate()` at `}};`

It should be `});` It will solve your error.